# Sharepoint/SPFx - Which component do you use to render RichText field?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, richtextbox, rich-text-editor, spfx

Which component (from which package) do you use to build rich text editor for rich text field with support for table creation for your SPFx projects?

So far I found "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/RichText" but it doesn't have support for table creation

Answer (score 0):

A good place to find out which “Rich-Text” Editors are right for you.

https://npmtrends.com/ckeditor-vs-draft-js-vs-froala-editor-vs-medium-editor-vs-quill-vs-slate-vs-tinymce